# Display some information on joptionpane

Tags: java

```
public class SimpleDialogueBox {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name");   
        String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("age");
        String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Address");
        String contact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Contact Number");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User information is", name);
    }
}
```

I want to have a display like this:

[image: display]

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the time to write a proper question with properly formatted code

Comment: The method takes a regular `String`, nothing fancy. Just build your desired `String` and display it.

Comment: I can't imagine a worse UI to interact with.  Do you want to pop up four successive option panes to get four pieces of related information?  I'm having seizures thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The method `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` takes a regular object to display, a `String` for example, nothing fancy. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)):

> `public static void showMessageDialog​(Component parentComponent, Object message) throws HeadlessException`
>
> Brings up an information-message dialog titled `"Message"`.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **`parentComponent`** - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if `null`, or if the `parentComponent` has no Frame, a default Frame is used
>
> **`message`** - the Object to display

So you just have to build the `String` you want to display and then you pass it to the method. You can concatenate `String`s using the `+` operator:

```
String lineSep = System.lineSeparator();
String message = "User information is: " + name + lineSep;
```

And so on. You can also use a `StringBuilder` for this purpose, it is also more efficient to use it for various reasons.

---

### Code

Here is the full code:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name");
String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("age");
String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Address");
String contact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Contact Number");

String lineSep = System.lineSeparator();
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append("User information is: ").append(lineSep).append(lineSep);
result.append("Name: ").append(name).append(lineSep);
result.append("Age: ").append(age).append(lineSep);
result.append("Address: ").append(address).append(lineSep);
result.append("Contact Number: ").append(contact);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result.toString());
```

And that is the resulting dialog:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks @Zabuza you have made my day

Comment: You're welcome. But next time please read through [help] and [ask]. And please consider **up-voting** and/or even **accepting** an answer that helped/solved your issue.